# Buffer Security Check (Stack Cookies)

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to enable buffer security check (stack cookies) for Delphi applications? And if it is possible, how?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. That feature does not exist in any of the Delphi (or C++Builder) compilers. That is a feature of Visual C++.